How To prove that if a matrix has two equal rows, then its determinant is zero using the Leibniz formula
Recently, while studying linear algebra, I came across the Leibniz formula. I've seen determinants handled in the form of Laplace expansion (cofactor expansion), but dealing with determinants using permutations is new to me, so I'm currently trying to prove some properties of determinants using the Leibniz formula. However, I'm not sure how to prove that the determinant is zero when a matrix has two identical rows.
Here's what I've attempted so far:
Let A=[$a_{ij}$]  be an $n\times n$ matrix where the $r$-th and $m$-th rows are identical.
Then By definition,
\begin{align}
detA&=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) a_{1\sigma(1)} \cdots a_{r\sigma(r)} \cdots a_{m\sigma(m)} \cdots a_{n\sigma(n)}\\
&=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) a_{1\sigma(1)} \cdots a_{m\sigma(m)} \cdots a_{m\sigma(m)} \cdots a_{n\sigma(n)}
\end{align}
To be honest, I'm not sure what to do from here, but if I think about it a bit more, the given expression would become zero if the terms cancel each other out when summed.
Therefore, to split the terms evenly, I considered dividing the permutations into even permutations and odd permutations, denoting them by $\sigma$ and $\tau$ respectively. Then,
detA$=\sum_{\sigma} \text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}a_{i\sigma(i)}+\sum_{\tau}\text{sgn}(\tau)\prod_{j=1}a_{j\sigma(j)}$
Since the sign is negative for odd permutations, the terms should cancel out appropriately.
What remains to be done is to show that the sum of the absolute values of the even permutations and the odd permutations are equal.
However, I'm not sure if this approach is correct, and I don't know how to proceed further from here.
What can I do?
I am using a translation tool, so I apologize in advance for any awkward expressions.
